# Concurrent users projected to actual users

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

I need to provide the business with a report estimating number of users (devices in this case) the system can cope with without extensive delays and errors.

Assuming each device polls-communicates with the server every 5 seconds or so would it be acceptable to multiple the number of concurrent users I stress test with by 5 to get the figure required by the business?

In general what are the best means of answering such a question considering the above factors?

I am guessing that the collision rate (making them concurrent) may well be over the ratio of 5 (the seconds it takes for the device before it asks to communicate with the server).

Any advice?

I am using JMeter to produce concurrent user/device throughput.

**Edit as requested to explain further:**

From an analytics point of view if each device will attempt to connect and communicate with the server every 5 seconds and we wish to receive a response within the time it is ready to re-communicate (in other words in next 4 seconds), the collision chances literally for other devices running the same software is calculated on the elapsed time between the two calls no?

I am looking for statistical analysis methodology really to find a percent to multiply the concurrent test results to a real environment.

I know it is a general question without a specific / explicit answer but more the methodology, if there is one, of how can one project the number of "active" users the system can cope with from the known "concurrent" users. I would have though that given the frequency of calls is known and that each call takes 300ms in average one could somehow project the actual users (maybe by an industry standard multiplier?)

Comment: This question is too broad and does not have a generic answer: it depends on your script, business goals and environment. You need to create analysis for your application and figure those numbers out. They are part of your testing outputs, not inputs.

Comment: Thank you @KirilS. Tried to expand as much as possible. It is really a case of trying to figure out if our current setup can cope with the volume of devices a client is looking to activate on the system (without service failure)